# Select currency (variable tickers)

Tags: pine-script

With a drop down menu I want to get data from multiple exchanges for a certain coin.
I'm not good at coding, I wrote this by looking at public scripts and modifying lines to fit mine.

```
@version=4
var string BTC = "BTC"
var string ETH = "ETH"

currency = input (BTC, title = "Currency", options=[BTC,ETH])

var cur1 = currency == BTC ? "INDEX:BTCUSD"      : "INDEX:ETHUSD"
var cur2 = currency == BTC ? "BITFINEX:BTCUSD"   : "BITFINEX:ETHUSD"
var cur3 = currency == BTC ? "HITBTC:BTCUSDT"    : "HITBTC:ETHUSD"

ticker_1 = input(cur1,            "", input.symbol)
ticker_2 = input(cur2,            "", input.symbol)
ticker_3 = input(cur3,            "", input.symbol)
```

I get this message for the line that starts with: *ticker_1 =...*:

> Cannot call 'input' with 'defval'=input string. The argument should be of type: const bool;

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

And second (assuming this is the right method), does this also work with more than two options?

Any help would be great.

**Edit**
This is the more complete code.

```
    var BTC = "BTC"
    var ETH = "ETH"
    
    currency = input (BTC, title = "Currency", options=[BTC,ETH])
    
    var cur1 = currency == BTC ? "INDEX:BTCUSD"      : "INDEX:ETHUSD"
    var cur2 = currency == BTC ? "BITFINEX:BTCUSD"   : "BITFINEX:ETHUSD"
    var cur3 = currency == BTC ? "HITBTC:BTCUSDT"    : "HITBTC:ETHUSD"
    
    // Inputs
    i_sym1          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="1",   group="Symbols")
    i_sym2          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="2",   group="Symbols")
    i_sym3          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="3",   group="Symbols")
    
    i_sym1_color    = input(#164F5C,            "", input.color,  inline="1",   group="Symbols")
    i_sym2_color    = input(#02C99A,            "", input.color,  inline="2",   group="Symbols")
    i_sym3_color    = input(#42ACDB,            "", input.color,  inline="3",   group="Symbols")
    
    i_sym1_ticker = input(cur1,            "", input.symbol, inline="1",   group="Symbols")
    i_sym2_ticker = input(cur2,            "", input.symbol, inline="2",   group="Symbols")
    i_sym3_ticker = input(cur3,            "", input.symbol, inline="3",   group="Symbols")
    
    f_volume(_ticker) => security(_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)

// Calculations
v1  =        i_sym1  ? f_volume(i_sym1_ticker)  : 0
v2  = v1  + (i_sym2  ? f_volume(i_sym2_ticker)  : 0)
v3  = v2  + (i_sym3  ? f_volume(i_sym3_ticker)  : 0)

// Plots
plot(v3 , style=plot_style, color=sym3_color,  linewidth=2, editable=false)
plot(v2 , style=plot_style, color=sym2_color,  linewidth=2, editable=false)
plot(v1 , style=plot_style, color=sym1_color,  linewidth=2, editable=false)
```

***Edit 2***

This is the entire script. This indicator shows the cumulative trading volume from different exchanges.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Aggregated Volume Colored", precision=0, overlay=false)
//
// Plot style selections
var string PS1 = "Columns"
var string PS2 = "Histogram"

// Inputs
i_sym1          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="1",   group="Symbols")
i_sym2          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="2",   group="Symbols")
i_sym3          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="3",   group="Symbols")

i_sym1_color    = input(#164F5C,            "", input.color,  inline="1",   group="Symbols")
i_sym2_color    = input(#02C99A,            "", input.color,  inline="2",   group="Symbols")
i_sym3_color    = input(#42ACDB,            "", input.color,  inline="3",   group="Symbols")

i_sym1_ticker = input("INDEX:BTCUSD",            "", input.symbol, inline="1",   group="Symbols", tooltip = "BTCUSD on MTGox, Bitstamp, Coinbase, Kraken and Gemini")
i_sym2_ticker = input("BITFINEX:BTCUSD",         "", input.symbol, inline="2",   group="Symbols")
i_sym3_ticker = input("HITBTC:BTCUSDT",          "", input.symbol, inline="3",   group="Symbols")


// Plot 
i_plot_style    = input(PS1,        "Plot style",       input.string, options=[PS1,PS2], group = "Plot")

i_single_color  = input(false,      "Use single color", input.bool,   inline="0",        group = "Plot")
i_default_color = input(color.gray, "",                 input.color,  inline="0",        group = "Plot")

price_enable    = input(false, "Show volume in quotation currency  (volume * price)", tooltip="This isn't accurate, just an estimation.",    group = "Plot") 

height          = input(100, "Height in % (For overlay on chart)", minval=0, maxval=100, step=5, tooltip = "How to: (Settings) set 'Bottom Margin' to 0 -> (Chart) Indicator name -> ●●● 'More' -> 'Move To' main pane -> 'Pin To Scale' -> 'No scale (Full Screen)' -> (Indicator Settings) -> Change Height in %'", group = "Plot")

// Variables
var int   plot_style   = i_plot_style == PS1 ? plot.style_columns : plot.style_histogram
var color sym1_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym1_color
var color sym2_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym2_color
var color sym3_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym3_color

// Functions
value = price_enable ? volume*ohlc4 : volume 

f_volume(_ticker) => security(_ticker, timeframe.period, value)

// Calculations
v1  =        i_sym1  ? f_volume(i_sym1_ticker)  : 0
v2  = v1  + (i_sym2  ? f_volume(i_sym2_ticker)  : 0)
v3  = v2  + (i_sym3  ? f_volume(i_sym3_ticker)  : 0)

// Plots
plot(v3 , style=plot_style, color=sym3_color,  linewidth=2, editable=false)
plot(v2 , style=plot_style, color=sym2_color,  linewidth=2, editable=false)
plot(v1 , style=plot_style, color=sym1_color,  linewidth=2, editable=false)
```

I just thought 'rewrite the code for variable plot style for variable tickers'.

```
// Plot style selections 
var string PS1 = "Columns" 
var string PS2 = "Histogram" 

// Plot 
i_plot_style = input(PS1, "Plot style", input.string, options=[PS1,PS2]) 
    
// Variables
var int plot_style = i_plot_style == PS1 ? plot.style_columns : plot.style_histogram
```

That is how I came up with this.

```
var string BTC = "BTC"
var string ETH = "ETH"
    
currency = input(BTC, "Currency", input.symbol, options=[BTC,ETH])
    
var  cur1 = currency == BTC ? "INDEX:BTCUSD"      : "INDEX:ETHUSD"
var  cur2 = currency == BTC ? "BITFINEX:BTCUSD"   : "BITFINEX:ETHUSD"
var  cur3 = currency == BTC ? "HITBTC:BTCUSDT"    : "HITBTC:ETHUSD"

i_sym1_ticker = input(cur1,            "", inline="1",   group="Symbols")
i_sym2_ticker = input(cur2,            "", inline="2",   group="Symbols")
i_sym3_ticker = input(cur3,            "", inline="3",   group="Symbols")
```

This is my edited script now.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Aggregated Volume Colored", precision=0, overlay=false)
//
// Plot style selections
var string PS1 = "Columns"
var string PS2 = "Histogram"

// Coin selections
var string BTC = "BTC"
var string ETH = "ETH"

currency = input(BTC, "Currency", input.symbol, options=[BTC,ETH])

var  cur1 = currency == BTC ? "INDEX:BTCUSD"      : "INDEX:ETHUSD"
var  cur2 = currency == BTC ? "BITFINEX:BTCUSD"   : "BITFINEX:ETHUSD"
var  cur3 = currency == BTC ? "HITBTC:BTCUSDT"    : "HITBTC:ETHUSD"

// Inputs
i_sym1          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="1",   group="Symbols")
i_sym2          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="2",   group="Symbols")
i_sym3          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="3",   group="Symbols")

i_sym1_color    = input(#164F5C,           "", input.color,  inline="1",   group="Symbols")
i_sym2_color    = input(#02C99A,           "", input.color,  inline="2",   group="Symbols")
i_sym3_color    = input(#42ACDB,           "", input.color,  inline="3",   group="Symbols")

i_sym1_ticker = input(cur1,                "", input.symbol, inline="1",   group="Symbols")
i_sym2_ticker = input(cur2,                "", input.symbol, inline="2",   group="Symbols")
i_sym3_ticker = input(cur3,                "", input.symbol, inline="3",   group="Symbols")

// Plot 
i_plot_style    = input(PS1,        "Plot style",       input.string, options=[PS1,PS2], group = "Plot")

i_single_color  = input(false,      "Use single color", input.bool,   inline="0",        group = "Plot")
i_default_color = input(color.gray, "",                 input.color,  inline="0",        group = "Plot")

// Variables
var int   plot_style   = i_plot_style == PS1 ? plot.style_columns : plot.style_histogram

var color sym1_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym1_color
var color sym2_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym2_color
var color sym3_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym3_color

// Functions
f_volume(_ticker) => security(_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)

// Calculations
v1  =        i_sym1  ? f_volume(i_sym1_ticker)  : 0
v2  = v1  + (i_sym2  ? f_volume(i_sym2_ticker)  : 0)
v3  = v2  + (i_sym3  ? f_volume(i_sym3_ticker)  : 0)

// Plots
plot(v3 , style=plot_style, color=sym3_color,  linewidth=2, editable=false)
plot(v2 , style=plot_style, color=sym2_color,  linewidth=2, editable=false)
plot(v1 , style=plot_style, color=sym1_color,  linewidth=2, editable=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that second set of inputs. It wouldn't work that way anyway because you cannot use `input string` as the default value. It expects a `constant string`.

`cur1`, `cur2` and `cur3` already have the ticker strings. So, you can directly use them like so:

```
cur2_close = security(cur2, timeframe.period, close)    
plot(cur2_close)
```

If you want to have a menu where the user can enter the ticker id himself, you need to use `input.symbol` input type:

```
in_ticker = input("", "Ticker", input.symbol)
ticker_close = security(in_ticker, timeframe.period, close)
plot(ticker_close)
```

Comment: Thank you @vitruvius for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't bring me further, I should have posted more of the code to give you a beter picture of what this script does.

I have edited the original post. Could you look at it again?

Comment: Why do you want to use `cur1` as default value of another input? You cannot do that, it is not possible.

Comment: I came up with cur1 as default by copying lines for an other function. 
I have updated the post again, now with the entire script with my reasoning for `cur1` as default. I get that it won't work this way. Is there a workaround?